# Hibernate: wrong value in list-index column for one-to-many relationship

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

Source code below works fine in most cases:

- each AClass has 10 items in the bclasses list
- all BClass records (10) related to one AClass have rank between 0 and 9

Sometimes I've seen another behavior after updating of AClass:

- each AClass has 10 items in the bclasses list
- all BClass records (10) related to one AClass have rank between 0 and 18, i.e. 0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18

Hibernate checks the maximum number in this list (18) and makes a decision to create a list of 19 items, all items between 1 and 9 IDs is null. As a result I have NullPointer in the setBclass method.

Some additional notes:

- There is no method on server side to add/delete BClass into/from the list
- Server side creates this list and set rank explicitly for each item in the list without gaps

Why rank values were changed ?

```
public class AClass implements Cloneable {
    private int id = -1;
    private List<BClass> bclasses;
    public void setBclass(List<BClass> bclasses) {
        this.bclasses= bclasses;
        for (BClass bclass : bclasses) {
            //do something with bclass
            //sometimes some items in the list is null
        }
    }
}

public class BClass implements Cloneable {
    private int id = -1;
    private byte rank;
}
```

Mapping:

```
<class name="AClass" table="aclass" >
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id              column="id"             name="id"             type="int"      unsaved-value="-1">
      <generator   class ="increment"/>  
    </id>
    <list name="bclasses"  table="bclass" cascade="all">
        <cache usage="nonstrict-read-write"/>
        <key            column="aclass_id"  />
        <list-index     column="rank"/>
        <one-to-many class="bclass" />
    </list>
</class>

<class name="BClass"  table="bclass">
    <cache usage="read-write"/>
    <id              column="id"             name="id"             type="int"      unsaved-value="-1">
        <generator   class ="increment"/>  
    </id>
    <property        column="rank"                       name="rank"                      type="byte" />
</class>
```

Comment: What are you doing with your classes?

Comment: It is example, in real applications these classes has much more fields and methods. Let's say AClass is a notebook with 10 sheets, BClass is sheet.

Comment: I mean what are you *doing* with it. The lists must get broken in one of the transactions ...

Comment: Nothing except getHibernateTemplate().update(AClass);

Comment: This question contains too little information.